# R - Split column values into new multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in the form:

```
    id          products
   1001     milk, cheese, sugar
   1002     milk
   1003     cheese, eggs
```

I would like to change it to a new data frame in the form :

```
id     product1    product2     product3
1001    milk        cheese        sugar
1002    milk        
1003    cheese       egg
```

How can I accomplish this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `separate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   separate(products, into = paste0('product', 1:3),
        sep=",\\s+", extra = "merge")  
#   id product1 product2 product3
#1 1001     milk   cheese    sugar
#2 1002     milk     <NA>     <NA>
#3 1003   cheese     eggs     <NA>
```

---

Or `cSplit` which would automatically detect the number of elements without having to specify the columns

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, 'products', ', ')
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1001:1003, products = c("milk, cheese, sugar", 
"milk", "cheese, eggs")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have non definite number of products in our dataframe (More than three). We can use `separate_rows()` from `tidyverse` without issues about the number of products and then reshape to wide. Here the code with data you shared (I added more items to see this approach). Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- structure(list(id = c(1001, 1002, 1003), products = c("milk, cheese, sugar, rice, soap, water", 
"milk", "cheese, eggs")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code:

```
#Code
df %>% separate_rows(products,sep = ', ') %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(Var=paste0('V',1:n())) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Var,values_from=products) %>%
  replace(is.na(.),'')
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
# Groups:   id [3]
     id V1     V2       V3      V4     V5     V6     
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  
1  1001 milk   "cheese" "sugar" "rice" "soap" "water"
2  1002 milk   ""       ""      ""     ""     ""     
3  1003 cheese "eggs"   ""      ""     ""     ""
```